# Why is 'n' not being updated after function call in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

First of all, I apologise if my question seemed vague however I had no idea how else to word it. 
Here is the code I am trying to run,

```
int insert(int *a, int n, int x, int pos){
if(pos>n){
    *(a+n)=x;
    n=n+1;
    print(a,n);
}
if(0<pos<n){
    for(int i=n;i>pos;i--){
        *(a+i)=*(a+i-1);
    }
    *(a+pos)=x;
    n=n+1;
    print(a,n); 
}
}

int main(){
int n=5;
    int *a, A[n]={1,7,3,4,5};
    a=A;
    insert(a,n,10,2);
    insert(a,n,100,2);
}
```

The issue I am running into is that the code is only printing 6 values even after the second 'insert' function call, even though it should print 6 values.
Currently my output is coming as: 
1 2 10 3 4 5
1 2 100 10 3 4 
And I am unable to fully grasp why. 
I understand that it may be because the variable **'n'** is *5* for both **'insert'** functions, and thus it prompts the compiler to only print *6* values, thereby not printing *5* in the second **'insert'** function.

However I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `n` is passed by value. This should be covered by any basic course or text on C++ functions.

Comment: Does it even compiles?

Comment: `int insert(...` but it appears that `insert` fails to `return` anything.

Comment: Change `0<pos<n` to `0<pos && pos < n`. As written it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: _"The issue [...] is that the code is only printing 6 values [...] even though it should print 6 values"_ ??? Doing what it is supposed to is an issue? Perhaps an explanation of what the code is supposed to do would help readers make sense of (presumably) typos like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not giving desired output because `int n` is passed to function `int insert(int *a, int n, int x, int pos)` as [call by value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference/) so changes made to `int n` are local to function `int insert(int *a, int n, int x, int pos)`.

Also, provided code doesn't compiles on ***GCC***, ***clang*** and ***VC++*** compilers.

Following is the error log on ***clang*** compiler:

```
main.cpp:8:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'print'
    print(a,n);
    ^
main.cpp:16:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'print'
    print(a,n); 
    ^
main.cpp:22:14: error: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wvla-extension]
    int *a, A[n]={1,7,3,4,5};
             ^
main.cpp:22:15: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    int *a, A[n]={1,7,3,4,5};
              ^
```

Following is the error log on ***GCC*** compiler:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int insert(int*, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:8:5: error: 'print' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'printf'?
    8 |     print(a,n);
      |     ^~~~~
      |     printf
main.cpp:10:5: warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]
   10 | if(0<pos<n){
      |    ~^~~~
main.cpp:16:5: error: 'print' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'printf'?
   16 |     print(a,n);
      |     ^~~~~
      |     printf
main.cpp:18:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   18 | }
      | ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:22:13: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'A' [-Wvla]
   22 |     int *a, A[n]={1,7,3,4,5};
      |             ^
```

Moreover, *this code will produce run-time error and crash on many environments because you are trying to push more elements in array `A` than its size*.

Following is corrected code. [You can see it working here](https://ideone.com/pYOI6Q):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 7

void print(int *a, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<*(a+i)<<" ";
}

int insert(int *a, int n, int x, int pos)
{
    if(pos>n)
    {
        *(a+n)=x;
        n=n+1;
        print(a,n);
    }
    if(0<pos && pos<n)
    {
        for(int i=n;i>pos;i--)
        {
            *(a+i)=*(a+i-1);
        }
        *(a+pos)=x;
        n=n+1;
        print(a,n); 
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int n=5;
    int *a, A[SIZE]={1,7,3,4,5};
    a=A;
    n = insert(a,n,10,2);
    insert(a,n,100,2);
    return 0;
}
```

**A more improved version of this [code can be found here](https://ideone.com/FwwsJ9)**